# Set default value to number column in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Trying to set default value of 10 digits to number column, type is INT. Gives error saying

## 1067 Invalid default value for number.

Also have set the lenght to 25.

Comment: what is your command used to try and create the column>

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Comment: Actually trying directly by editing the structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want to set any random 10 digit number then, assign the type as bigint.
If the the random 10 digit is in range between -2147483648 to 2147483647 then type int is will do .

The datatype INT uses 4 bytes (from -2147483648 to 2147483647 or unsigned from 0 to 4294967295),
the datatype BIGINT uses 8 bytes (from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 or unsigned from 0 to 18446744073709551615).

Answer (score 2):

> Gives error saying #1067 Invalid default value for number.

Make sure the value you are providing is within the range of acceptable values for [`INT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) type. That is: `-2147483648 <= your_value <=  2147483647`

Not sure how you are trying but below command should work

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY `column_name` INT DEFAULT 9;
```

Comment: @RupaliPemare, so what value you are trying to add exactly?

Comment: Any 10 digit number

Comment: @RupaliPemare, no idea unless you post your table structure. see edit in answer if helps

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your number lies within the range? 
Please post your table structure or 10 digit number you are trying to set as default value.